# How to run test cases in different Java classes in a new window every time using TestNG and Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, testng, selenium-chromedriver

I have 15 test methods in 3 Java classes (Selenium Script). I want to run each Test class with new window. I am using TestNg framework.

Here is the code of TestNG:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Fanfight Test" thread-count="10" parallel="methods">
    <listeners>
         <listener class-name="com.fanfight.test_case.ListenerClass">
         </listener>
     </listeners>
    <test name="User Login" parallel="false">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.fanfight.test_case.UserLogin"></class>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Contest Creation" parallel="false" >
        <classes>
            <class name="com.fanfight.test_case.ContestCreation"></class>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="User Profile Test" parallel="false" >
        <classes>
            <class name="com.fanfight.test_case.UserProfileTest"></class>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Menu Bar Test" parallel="false">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.fanfight.test_case.MenuBarTest">

            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Home Page Elements" parallel="false" >
        <classes>
            <class name="com.fanfight.test_case.HomePageElementTest"></class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Without using `parallel="false"` my script is running in alphabetical order due to which selenium unable to find the path and execution got stuck.

Also please suggest how to make execution continue even after getting an  exception during execution.

Comment: If you want to run classes in parallel then use parallel="classes"

Comment: You might want to have a TearDown method that you can call after each test case run. TearDown would include a Driver.Close()

Comment: Implement a BaseTest class, that every test classes extend from. Then in BaseTest class create a TestStart method and TestTearDown method. TestStart method should have webdriver iniatlization and TearDown should have a function to close the webdriver. And each of your test classes should extend the BaseTest .

Answer (score 0):

Add a setup and tear down method in each of the 3 test classes. The setup method should launch the browser and teardown method should close that browser instance.

```
class TestOne {
WebDriver driver;
@BeforeClass
public void setup(){
 driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
}
@Test
public void testCase1(){
}
//.... Other test methods
@AfterClass
public void tearDown(){
driver.quit();
}
```

You can also create a parent class having just the setup and tear down methods , pseudo coded above. All 3 of your test class shall extend this parent class. It will be an optimised approach as the driver instantiation and destruction is now centralised to a single class.

And finally , change the parallel attribute in the suite tag of your testNG xml, in order to make them run parallel.

```
<suite name="Fanfight Test" thread-count="10" parallel="classes">
```